# R: How to use the first value from a column in a calculation, then switch to this result for the following rows

Tags: r, algorithm

This is a example of the data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  dept = c(rep('FIREDEPT', 5), rep('WATERDEPT', 5)),
  month = 201808:201812,
  initial_stock = sample(75884:85347, 10),
  variable_predicted = sample(50000:100000, 10),
  variable2_predicted= sample(1:100, 10) / 100)
```

I need to create a new field called "predicted_stock", and it needs to use the follow calculation by department:

- if month is the first month, then calculate initial_stock +
  variable_predicted * variable2_predicted
- if month is not the first, then use the previous predicted_stock + variable_predicted * variable2_predicted

I could only think of doing this with a for loop approach, but I don't think that is very smart... What would be an optimal way of doing this calculation?

Comment: You need to clarify what `variable_predicted` and `variable2_predicted` are, they do not match your example data.

Comment: I forgot to put the same name on the code, sorry. It is just a token variable to represent the calculation, the important part is being able to use the result from the previous row in an incremental way, but using a different calculation on the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do it using @user2738526 post. Don't think it's the optimal way still, but better than what I was trying to do initially.

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
# if first month, than use intial stock
# I "recalculate" the initial_stock, 
# this is specific to the real scenario
df <- df %>% mutate(initial_stock = 
                      ifelse(month == min(month), 
                        initial_stock, 
                        0
                        )
                    )

# calculate the predicted stock using cumsum
df <- df %>% group_by(DEPTO) %>% mutate(predicted_stock =
                                          cumsum(
                                            initial_stock 
                                            + variable_predicted * variable2_predicted
                                          )
                                        )
# "recalculation" of the initial_sock is updated
# this is specific to the real scenario
df <- df %>% group_by(DEPTO) %>% mutate(initial_sock = 
                                        ifelse(month == min(month), 
                                            initial_stock , 
                                            shift(predicted_stock, type = "lag")
                                            )
                                        )
```

Comment: Minor improvement: `ifelse(cond, x, 0)` could be `cond*x`. Btw, you should list your packages even if they're the same as the other answer. (I guess they're not, since dplyr doesn't include `shift`)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on whether your df is always sorted with the first row in each department being the row you want different then you could use either of the following:

```
library(dplyr) 
df %>% group_by(dept) %>% mutate(predicted_stock= ifelse(row_number()==1, "CalcA", "CalcB"))
df %>% group_by(dept) %>% mutate(predicted_stock= ifelse(month==min(month), "CalcA", "CalcB"))
```

I'm assuming you can fill in what the calculations are as the equation you have given do not use the example columns you have provided.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, this code doesn't use the previous value from the predicted stock, since it is not recorded yet, so the second calculation does't work.